# Closures in Java

Tags: java, lambda, closures

This example is a simulation of closures in JavaScript (I don't know JS):

```
public class Lambda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier generator = Lambda.generator();
        System.out.println(generator.get());
        System.out.println(generator.get());
        System.out.println(generator.get());
    }

    static Supplier<Integer> generator() {
        Integer arr[] = {0};
        return () -> ++arr[0];
    }
}
```

The output is 1 2 3.
Usually the lifespan of local method variables is limited by the method execution time. But in this case the reference to `arr[]` is stored somewhere. So where is it stored and what's under the hood?

Answer (score 4):

The Java Language Specification ([§15.27.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4)) says:

> The value of a lambda expression is a reference to an instance of a class with the following properties:
>
> - The class implements the targeted functional interface type ...

So the lambda defines a class, much like an anonymous class declaration does, and the lambda expression results in a reference to an instance of that class. The reference to `arr` is held by a synthetic `final` field belonging to that instance.

---

Here's an example using reflection in the JShell REPL, to demonstrate a lambda with a synthetic field:

```java
> class A { static Runnable a(int x) { return () -> System.out.println(x); } }
| created class A

> Runnable r = A.a(5);
r ==> A$$Lambda$15/1476394199@31ef45e3

> import java.lang.reflect.Field;

> Field f = r.getClass().getDeclaredFields()[0];
f ==> private final int A$$Lambda$15/1476394199.arg$1

> f.setAccessible(true);

> f.get(r)
$6 ==> 5
```

Comment: Thank you, could you also give a reference to "synthetic final field"?

Comment: Hard to get an authoritative one, since it's more like an implementation detail than a specified behaviour. The JVMS defines what "synthetic" means, but doesn't specify all cases where it applies: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.8 This article shows a decompiled lambda with a synthetic field named `cap$0`: http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1353 The book *Java Closures and Lambda* by Robert Fischer (2015) talks about synthetic fields for lambdas on page 152.

Comment: I've added an example showing a synthetic field via reflection in the REPL, if that helps.